# Rewriting .txt to array by scanner

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Materials implements Runnable {
    String path;

    public Materials(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public int checkSize() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path));
        int size = 0;
            while(sc.hasNextLine()) size++;
        sc.close();
        return size;
    }

    public void run() {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File(path));
        int[][] materialsTab = new int[1][checkSize()];
        int x=0, count=0;
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            count++;

            materialsTab[x][0] = sc.nextInt();
            materialsTab[x][1] = sc.nextInt();
            x++;
            System.out.println("Im working!");

            if(count%200 == 0) System.out.println("Creat " + count + " objects");
    }
    sc.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }
}
```

My problem is that I have to rewrite .txt file into an array by thread, then comes the next thread, but I got stuck at the first part of the task.

public int checkSize () is responsible for counting the size of the array, because the text file consists of about 10 000 lines. The whole will look exactly like this:

[Product ID] [Weight]

So I decided to count the number of lines and create just such a table, one place where I keep ID, and next to the weight, because later I will have to count a few things.

In addition, every 200 records must appear in the message. The problem is that after starting this part...  nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
int[][] materialsTab ...
```

consider using something roughly like:

```
List<Point> materialsTab = new ArrayList<Point>();

Point mat = new Point();
mat.x = sc.nextInt();
if (!sc.hasNext())
    break;
mat.y = sc.nextInt();
materialsTab.add(mat);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, try changing `Runnable` to `Callable<int[]>` and `public void run()` to `public int[] call()` and adding `return materialsTab;` at the end.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt help :( if its helpful i can add main class too.